# crosfilter dropdown filter and line chart not working together

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am attempting to filter a d3/dc line chart using drop downs attached to the crossfilter instance
I have a fiddle of what I have tried.

https://jsfiddle.net/xxjpusa7/200/

the console logs on the change events of the drop downs show the data that I want charted which I *believe* is what I have asked the chart to render.
the chart never renders any data only the gridlines.

there are no errors and no indication of what might be wrong so I am at a loss.

completely new to crossfilter/d3/dc but loving the pain of the new so feel free to slap me with documentation that I have read but maybe missed the pertinent point.

here is the code for the dimension, group and chart

```
datedim = cf.dimension(function(d){return dateFormat2(d.Created); })  

       var grouped = datedim.group().reduce(reduceAddFinancial,reduceRemoveFinancial,reduceInitFinancial)

lineChart
      .height(350)
      .width(1200)
      .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
      .dimension(datedim)
      .group(grouped)
      .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2019, 12, 31)]))
      .elasticY(true)
      .renderHorizontalGridLines(true);
```

Comment: Here's some documentation for you to read: [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- please post your code here. :)  If you could also use the 'preview' tab to check your question is formatted nicely prior to posting, that will make it easier for other users to view your code and help you out. Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out myself datedim = cf.dimension(function(d){return dateFormat2(d.Created); })  was wrong

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions related to the charting library. [dc] is the classic Unix command "desktop calculator". :-)

Comment: @RichardDavison : What is the corrected `datedim` line?